# providing user input for a java class

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
class Area
{
    //Get User Input for classes
    int length;
    int width;

    public Area(int x,int y)
    {
        length = x;
        width = y;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return width * length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Area folk = new Area(4,5);
        System.out.println("Area of 4 * 5 is: " + folk.getArea());
    }
}
```

I have another class that i use to get user input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Incoming
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        //get user input for a
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input Value Is: " + a);
    }
}
```

In the first class i want a user to provide the input instead of the predefined values (i.e. `Area folk = new Area(4,5)`)

How can that be done?

Comment: um,.. use the int that the user enters in the constructor's parameter perhaps. In other words create two int variables a, and b, get your user input using Scanner, and then call the Area constructor with a and b.

Comment: You can read a detailed tutorial about it here:http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/ndale/Scanner.html

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full Of Eels,that worked.

Comment: This worked http://pastebin.com/J2Hf5xF0

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're looking for a way to use the input provided in `Incoming` elsewhere in your program.

To do this, move the code to get input out of the `main` method. Declare a new method in `Incoming` that returns an `int` and put it there.

Then, in the `main` method of `Area`, create an instance of `Incoming` and call the new method to get an `int`. Do this twice, then pass the resulting values to the `Area` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have a main in both of your classes.  Maybe I'm mis-understanding something, but this will fix it the way you want (I think).

```
class Area
{
    //Get User Input for classes
    int length;
    int width;

    public Area(int x,int y)
    {
        length = x;
        width = y;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        return width * length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int x, y;
        Incoming inc = new Incoming();
        x = inc.getInt();
        y = inc.getInt();
        Area folk = new Area(x,y);
        System.out.println("Area of " + x + " * " + y + " is: "
                           + folk.getArea());
    }
}
```

And the other class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Incoming
{
    public static int getInt(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first number");
        //get user input for a
        int a = reader.nextInt();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: The two classes were showing what i was trying to do.I have a link here of the two together http://pastebin.com/J2Hf5xF0

Answer (score 0):

how about:

Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

Area folk = new Area(reader.nextInt(),reader.nextInt());

system.out.println(folk.getArea());